# How to query Wolfram Alpha to find projection of point on plane?

Tags: vector, wolfram-alpha-queries

For example, the projection of the point $P=(1,2,3)$ on the plane $x+y+z=3$ is the point $Q=(0,1,2)$.

How do I ask Wolfram Alpha to compute this? I've tried "[projection of point (1,2,3) on plane x+y+z=3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=projection%20of%20point%20(1,2,3)%20on%20plane%20x%2By%2Bz%3D3)", but this doesn't work.

Comment: You can [read in the help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that some kinds of questions are considered [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD):

Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay).
Questions on licensing, specific support arrangements, product availability and pre-release versions of Mathematica — please contact Wolfram Support at support@wolfram.com.
Questions about the site itself — please ask on the [meta] site instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern Mathematica.  Try Wolfram Community for purely W|A-related questions.